# Not able to add a new column to an existing schema using springboot

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

In the properties file I have given
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.default_schema = schema.sql

```
@Builder
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table
public class TestCase implements Comparable<TestCase>{
    @Id
    // @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    
    private String testCaseId;

    private String fxQuoteUniqueId;
    private String ENRICHMENT_APIUniqueId;

    private String APVUniqueId; // added a new column.
}
```

after maven clean install i am running the API and sending the request through postman
but the APVUniqueId is getting null value.  Is there any other place I have to give the mapping

Comment: Maybe you should consider using Flyway instead of ddl-auto-update. Spring integrates Flyway natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. I had to use the camel case for the new column.

private String apvUniqueId;

renamed as above